# Detect, identify & Extract Screenshots from iPhone using combination of iOS app & Windows program

Tags: windows, ios, photography, screenshot, iphone-app

I have taken a lot of screenshots on my iPhone over a long time for
lots of reasons.

I need to be able to extract from iPhone to Windows 8.1 desktop, ALL
of them or SELECTED bunch/groups of them; bonus if I can sort/filter some way.

Given the structures & mechanisms of iOS 9.x it seems to keep/mark or
filter all or most screenshots as if in a subfolder under Photos
called "Screenshots". From what I gather this is kind of a virtual folder on iOS.

I am wondering if there are iOS apps & Windows programs that I can use
in conjunction to extract these screenshots from the iPhone and
"permanently delete" them from the phone as they are taking up space.

I know for sure that I can't do this purely via software/apps on one platform {except option 4 below}. I'd be surprised if there is a way.

Most likely I'll need one or more of the following pieces/ scenarios:

1. iOS app

   that can organize, tag, move or permanently create an isolated folder of screenshots or something that can be filtered/recognized from the Windows side as a separate 'entity' {Given that even all subfolders under Photos are technically only one large folder of Photos}
2. Windows desktop application/program

   that allows me to selectively target this specific folder/virtual folder tag

Ideally, both of these are from a common vendor designed to work well together.

3. A new scenario that popped up in my head: An iOS app that allows us to export & clear out all these screenshots to a flash/memory/external disk - then it should be simpler to manage that exported lot from Windows.